# TimeSpan still not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, session-state, timespan

Heres the code I have re arranged, but still have same problem, not able to find my start and end times on last page? How do I do this?

```
public void start()
    {
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    protected void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        start();
        Response.Redirect("~/end.aspx");
    }
```

---

```
public void end()
    {
        DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
    protected void btnEnd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        end();
        Response.Redirect("~/display.aspx");
    }
```

---

```
public partial class display : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan timeSpent = endTime - startTime;

        lblDisplay.Text = string.Format("Time: {0}", timeSpent);
    }
}
```

---

Now can anyone help me on this? Should I use session, if I should, how do I use it with datetime and timespan, etc. Thanks!

Comment: You're declaring *local* variables for `startTime` and `endTime`... they have scope just for the methods in which you're declaring them.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm going to make them in a class and see if I can get it! Thanks @JonSkeet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem :** You are declaring your `startTime` and `endTime` variables inside the functions as below:

```
public void start()
{
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now; //remove the declartion from here
}

public void end()
{
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now; //remove the declaration from here
}
```

**Solution :** Declare your `startTime` and `endTime` variables as class variables and then assign the values in the `start()` and `end()` functions.

Try This:

```
DateTime startTime; //declare here
DateTime endTime;   //declare here

public void start()
{
    startTime = DateTime.Now; //assign value here
}
public void end()
{
    endTime = DateTime.Now;  //assign value here
}
```